# How can I read a file with lines separated by a regular expression

Tags: regex, csv, awk, sed

I have a csv file with embedded newlines characters.

What I'd like to do is re-write each line with a different EOL character to make parsing by other CSV reader's simpler.

To that end, I know each new line starts with the regular expression /\n"\d+","/  -- which is a newline, quote, some digits, another quote, a comma, then another quote.

I may be wrong, but sed, awk, and most other tools expect a newline at the end.  Is there a linux tool that doesn't?

My next idea is to use awk to keep reading lines and push them to a buffer until it finds one starting with the expression above--then it will write it out.

Comment: Awk RS sets the record separator

Comment: Proper CSV parsers will accept quoted fields containing newlines. Please show a sample of your input data.

Comment: "to keep reading lines and push them to a buffer", you can do the same with sed.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's see if I understand what you want correctly. Given a csv file like

```
"123","foo
bar","baz"
"234","quxqux"
"345","xy
zz
y","asd"
```

you would like it transformed into something like

```
"123","fooNEWLINEbar","baz"
"234","quxqux"
"345","xyNEWLINEzzNEWLINEy","asd"
```

Then the best I can whip up on short notice (without going back to the sed docs properly prepared to maintain sanity) is this sed script:

```
/^"[0-9]\+","/ !H
/^"[0-9]\+","/ {
  x
  s/\n/NEWLINE/g
  p
  x
  h
}
$ {
  x
  s/\n/NEWLINE/g
  p
  x
  h
}
```

to be used, if the code is in file `foo.sed`, like this:

```
sed -n -f foo.sed foo.csv
```

**Explanation:**

This goes into some of the lesser-used features of sed, so I'll briefly explain two basic mechanisms:

1. Pattern ranges

A sed command of the form

```
/regex1/ command
```

will apply command to all lines that `regex1` can match. For example,

```
/^1/ s/2/3/g
```

will replace `2`s with `3`s in all lines that begin with `1`. `!` inverts the match, so

```
/^1/ !s/2/3/g
```

replaces `2`s with `3`s in all lines that *don't* start with 1. Commands can be grouped with `{}`

2. The hold buffer

This is one of the lesser-known but very powerful features of sed. Most sed commands work on the pattern space. The pattern space is where new lines of input are written so commands can  work on them, so if you're treating lines individually, this mechanic is transparent to you. In addition, sed has a hold buffer where you can hold on to previous input because you'll need it later. There are only a few commands that work on the hold buffer; three of them are of interest to us: `h`, `H` and `x`. `h` copies the current contents of the pattern space (usually the line of input that was just written there) to the hold buffer. `H` appends the pattern space to the hold buffer. `x` swaps the contents of the pattern space and hold buffer.

Taking the script block by block:

```
/^"[0-9]\+","/ !H
```

This applies to all lines that *don't* start with `"number","` the H command. This means that those lines are appended to the hold buffer.

```
/^"[0-9]\+","/ {
  x
  s/\n/NEWLINE/g
  p
  x
  h
}
```

This applies to all lines that *do* start with `"number","` the block of commands. That is:

- swap the pattern space and hold buffer
- Replace newlines in the pattern space (that used to be the hold buffer) with NEWLINE
- Print that stuff
- swap back (pattern space is now the new input line again)
- Write the pattern space to the hold buffer, overwriting what was there before

Lastly,

```
$ {
  x
  s/\n/NEWLINE/g
  p
  x
  h
}
```

does the same thing for the last line of input, so the last logical line of the CSV is not lost.

This means that all parts of a "logical line" of the CSV are assembled in the hold buffer, and when the start of the next one is detected, the assembled line is mangled appropriately and printed.